# GCP Datastore Java API, build an entity with null value

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

So this is not much of a "I have a bug how to fix it" question as much as "Is this really how this works?" question.

So, I am looking over my code to persist an entity into datastore, and if I try to set an attribute that is null, all hell breaks lose. I noticed that there's a `setNull` but is that it? I have to manually check every attribute before building it in order to call the appropriate `set`? Shouldn't the standard set, which is overloaded for a plethora of datatypes handle null on itself?

Here is a code piece

```
public void put(BatchExecution obj) {
    Key key = keyFactory.newKey(obj.getId());           
    FullEntity<Key> incBEEntity = Entity.newBuilder(key)  
        .set(BatchExecution.ID, obj.getId())
        .set(BatchExecution.NAME, obj.getName())
        .set(BatchExecution.CREATETIME, obj.getCreateTime())
        .set(BatchExecution.ELAPSEDTIME, obj.getElapsedTime()) //I break the code because elapesedTime was never set in the object
        .set(BatchExecution.STATUS, obj.getStatus().name())
        .build();
    datastore.put(incBEEntity);
  }
```

Am I missing something here or is this really how the API works?

Comment: You could do as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40965030/3058302) and use [`NullValue.of()`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/NullValue.java)

Comment: @Mangu That's exactly what I don't want to do and Shouldn't have to. Manually checking if an attribute is null and calling a different method based on that is NOT the API's client concern, it's an API concern. SET is overloaded so I can call it to any supported datatype without knowing about the internal implementation of it. If I have to call a different method to set a NULL value, this means that an internal API implementation concern is exposed to the API's client, which is wrong. Furthermore, there's already a Null check in the API stack call, that's what threw the exception in the ...

Comment: first place, so it is really so unreal to want that check to be upper on the stack and each SET method do said check and if the value is null call the setNull from within the API, without exposing that to the user? Is this really so far fetched?. Also, I noticed you are a Support for GCP, let me know if you think I should open this as an enhancement ticket on github

Comment: I just recommended what I saw from reading into it, if you wish to take this issue in to the Java dev team, the official Github repo [is here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concern raised on github
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/3583

Question has been closed.